# Serializing JSON response in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I would need assistance in serializing the below JSON Response. By far, I've managed to only extract the `district` property but cannot seem to understand how to go about with the properties of `ward_no`. The code for what I've done is below. Please note that I would like to serialize the JSON response in the same approach as on my code as I found it nearly impossible to wrap my head around the Serializing techniques suggested in the Official Documents.

The Response:

```
[
    {
        "district": "Kolkata",    //I've only managed to extract this.
        "ward_no": [
            {
                "ward": "6",     
                "grievance": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0001",
                        "name": "Siddhartha Chatterjee"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0002",
                        "name": "Sajujjo Ghosh"
                    }
                ],
                "general": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0003",
                        "name": "Dr. Partha Pratim Paul"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0004",
                        "name": "Dr. Partha Pratim Paul"
                    }
                ],
                "urgent": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0005",
                        "name": "Ritwick Banerjee"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0006",
                        "name": "Soumadip Banerjee"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0007",
                        "name": "Tanajeet Biswas"
                    },
                    {
                        "serial_number": "0008",
                        "name": "Durba Chatterjee"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Model {
  final String district;

  Model({required this.district});
}

class ModelClass with ChangeNotifier {
  List<dynamic> _data = [];

  List<dynamic> get data {
    return [..._data];
  }

  Future<void> getData() async {
    final url = Uri.http('192.168.0.6:3007', '/fetchData');
    final response = await http.get(url);
    print(response);
    final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
    print(extractedData);
    Map<String, Model> temp = {};
    extractedData.forEach((value) {
      temp.putIfAbsent(
          value['_id'],
          () =>
              Model(district: value['district']));
    });
    print(temp);
    _data = temp.values.toList();
    print(_data);
  }
}
```

P.S: I'm not looking to use boilerplate code generated by those JSON to Dart converter links

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tools which will generate data class form the provided json
https://jsontodart.zariman.dev/

```
class Response {
    String? district;
    List<WardNo>? wardNo;

    Response({this.district, this.wardNo});

    Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        this.district = json["district"];
        this.wardNo = json["ward_no"]==null ? null : (json["ward_no"] as List).map((e)=>WardNo.fromJson(e)).toList();
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data["district"] = this.district;
        if(this.wardNo != null)
            data["ward_no"] = this.wardNo?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
        return data;
    }
}

class WardNo {
    String? ward;
    List<Grievance>? grievance;
    List<General>? general;
    List<Urgent>? urgent;
    List<Services>? services;

    WardNo({this.ward, this.grievance, this.general, this.urgent, this.services});

    WardNo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        this.ward = json["ward"];
        this.grievance = json["grievance"]==null ? null : (json["grievance"] as List).map((e)=>Grievance.fromJson(e)).toList();
        this.general = json["general"]==null ? null : (json["general"] as List).map((e)=>General.fromJson(e)).toList();
        this.urgent = json["urgent"]==null ? null : (json["urgent"] as List).map((e)=>Urgent.fromJson(e)).toList();
        this.services = json["services"]==null ? null : (json["services"] as List).map((e)=>Services.fromJson(e)).toList();
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data["ward"] = this.ward;
        if(this.grievance != null)
            data["grievance"] = this.grievance?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
        if(this.general != null)
            data["general"] = this.general?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
        if(this.urgent != null)
            data["urgent"] = this.urgent?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
        if(this.services != null)
            data["services"] = this.services?.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
        return data;
    }
}

class Services {
    String? serialNumber;
    String? name;

    Services({this.serialNumber, this.name});

    Services.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        this.serialNumber = json["serial_number"];
        this.name = json["name"];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data["serial_number"] = this.serialNumber;
        data["name"] = this.name;
        return data;
    }
}

class Urgent {
    String? serialNumber;
    String? name;

    Urgent({this.serialNumber, this.name});

    Urgent.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        this.serialNumber = json["serial_number"];
        this.name = json["name"];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data["serial_number"] = this.serialNumber;
        data["name"] = this.name;
        return data;
    }
}

class General {
    String? serialNumber;
    String? name;

    General({this.serialNumber, this.name});

    General.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        this.serialNumber = json["serial_number"];
        this.name = json["name"];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data["serial_number"] = this.serialNumber;
        data["name"] = this.name;
        return data;
    }
}

class Grievance {
    String? serialNumber;
    String? name;

    Grievance({this.serialNumber, this.name});

    Grievance.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        this.serialNumber = json["serial_number"];
        this.name = json["name"];
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data["serial_number"] = this.serialNumber;
        data["name"] = this.name;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: So where exactly is all this getting stored for me to be able to use in my app? If you look at the code I've written above, you'll see that I made a getter function named data to store all the data. I would like to know, what I need to do here to have something like that.

Comment: Because let's say If I wanted to filter data based on certain criteria, I would need all this information stored at one common place like say a list or a map. I don't see how that can be achieved when the data is all scattered here and there

Comment: You can use where condition in the list of result